# JAX-RS Path with count regular expression

Tags: jax-rs, eclipse-oxygen

If I use the "{}" to specify the count condition in the regular expression of JAX-RS `@Path`, eclipse throws as error.

```
@Path("/apps/{itemId:\\d{10}}")
public Response getItems(...
```

> The @Path annotation value `'/apps/{itemId:\d{10}}'` is invalid:
>   missing '{' or '}'.

Is above JAX-RS Path not a valid path ? Is it due to eclipse JAX-RS validator problem ? If I just specify `@Path("/apps/{itemId}")` there is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use curly brackets inside variable when [using regex in Path annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html#value--). Use instead:

```
@Path("/apps/{itemId: \\d+}")
```

> regex = *( nonbrace / "{" *nonbrace "}" ) ; where nonbrace is any char other than "{" and "}"

Theoretically you can check 10 digits as you want using multiple `[0-9]`:

```
@Path("/apps/{itemId: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}")
```

Comment: it is strange that '{' is not accepted. I would rather accept all digits and validate after that. Thanks.

Comment: @ulab they probably wanted to avoid handling special cases with inner/multiple curly braces